# How does caret choose default tuning range?

Tags: r, r-caret

When using `R` `caret` to compare multiple models on the same data set, `caret` is smart enough to select different tuning ranges for different models if the same `tuneLength` is specified for all models and no model-specific `tuneGrid` is specified.

For example, the tuning ranges chosen by `caret` for one particular data set are:

`earth(nprune)`: 2, 5, 8, 11, 14

`gamSpline(df)`: 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3

`rpart(cp)`: 0.010, 0.054, 0.116, 0.123, 0.358

How does `caret` determine these default tuning ranges? I have been searching through the documentation but still haven't pinned down the algorithm to choose the ranges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the model. For `rpart` and a few others, it fits and initial model to get a sense of what reasonable values should be. In other cases, it is less intelligent. For example, for `gamSpline` it is `expand.grid(df = seq(1, 3, length = len))`.

You can see what it does per model using `getModelInfo`:

```
 > getModelInfo("earth")[[1]]$grid
 function(x, y, len = NULL) {
       dat <- if(is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x)
       dat$.outcome <- y

       mod <- earth( .outcome~., data = dat, pmethod = "none")
       maxTerms <- nrow(mod$dirs)
       maxTerms <- min(200, floor(maxTerms * .75) + 2)
       data.frame(nprune = unique(floor(seq(2, to = maxTerms, length = len))),
                  degree = 1)
  }
```

Max